# Impute missing values with prediction from linear regression in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm working with this Dataframe named `na` where I filtered only the missing values, all included in the `d` column

```
        genuine     a       b   c       d       e       f
23      True    171.94  103.89  103.45  NaN     3.25    112.79
75      True    171.60  103.85  103.91  NaN     2.56    113.27
210     True    172.03  103.97  103.86  NaN     3.07    112.65
539     False   172.07  103.74  103.76  NaN     3.09    112.41
642     True    172.14  104.06  103.96  NaN     3.24    113.07
780     True    172.41  103.95  103.79  NaN     3.13    113.41
798     True    171.96  103.84  103.62  NaN     3.01    114.44
```

I used the Sklearn linear regression to train and test a model to predict `d` values based on `f` column

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# data prep
df = df_data.dropna(axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
X = np.array(df['f']).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(df['d'])

# Split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=42)
  
# Training
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluation
print(f"score: {lin_reg.score(X_test, y_test)}")
print(f"intercept: {lin_reg.intercept_}")
print(f"slope: {lin_reg.coef_}")
```

Then I used this model to predict

```
# new dataframe with only the missing data as shown previously
na = df_data[df_data['d'].isnull()]

x_null = na['f'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y_null = lin_reg.predict(x_null)
```

So now `y_null` returned an array so I don't know how to impute those predicted values into the `na` dataframe and then to the `df_data` to fill the missing values.

If I use `na.fillna({'d': y_null})` it returns an error as `"value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "ndarray"`
Moreover, I tried to use a lambda function but I didn't succeed.

I want to be sure about the well correspondence with the `y_null` predicted to go the right row in the `d` column. I assumed `y_null` array is sorted by the `na` index position ?

How to impute the predicted values instead of the NaN?

Comment: predict on `df["f"]` then use `[pandas.Series.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)` to fill your `d` column with the predictions (you might need to wrap it in a Series, and index with `df.index`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this topic, I finally found a way to do it (I suppose another code could be more efficient but for now it works with this one).

```
#create a new DF to store prediction and ID position
df_null = pd.DataFrame(y_null, columns=['prevision'])

#reset index on na DF
nan=na.copy().reset_index()

#add column in the nuw nan DF
df_prev=pd.concat([nan, df_null], axis=1)

#set index
df_prev = df_prev.set_index('index')

#fill the values
df_ok = df_data.fillna({'d':df_prev['prevision']}).copy()
```

So Now I'm sure the values added are sharing the same index so I shouldn't be wrong with `fillna()`

Answer (score -1):

Always use Preprocessing Data.

```
df.info()___Show null columns
df.isnull().sum()______Show missing values
```

you can:

1.Dropping missing data:

```
df.drop(['col1', 'col2'], axis=1, inplace=True)___delete columns

df.dropna(inplace=True)_____delete rows(if contain Nan)
```

2. Imputing missing data:

   df['col1'].fillna(df['col1'].mean(), inplace=True)

more info: [link](https://www.jcchouinard.com/preprocessing-in-scikit-learn/)